# UnicodeEncodeError on API-call (json)

Tags: python, json, api, unicode, python-unicode

I am trying to print out the result of this API-call, but I am getting an UnicodeEncodeError. Probably super noob question, but would really appreciate any help with this :)

```
import http.client
import json

api_key = 'hidden'
connection = http.client.HTTPConnection('api.football-data.org')
headers = { 'X-Auth-Token': api_key, 'X-Response-Control': 'minified' }
connection.request('GET', '/v1/competitions', None, headers)
response = json.loads(connection.getresponse().read().decode())

print(response)
```

Error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/kjetilbergtun/Dropbox/My Python Projects/footballapi.py", line 13, in 
    print(response)

**UnicodeEncodeError**: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xe9' in position 51: ordinal not in range(128)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`encode` is used by `print` to convert the Unicode characters in your string to a byte stream that can be sent to your output device.

Before you start Python, you can set the environment variable [`PYTHONIOENCODING`](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONIOENCODING) to the encoding required by your console. I'd recommend trying `mbcs` on Windows and `utf-8` everywhere else if you don't know what that should be. If you don't provide an encoding the default will be `ascii`, which only works on the simplest strings.

Comment: That works! I used PYTHONIOENCODING='utf_8'.

Also, for people working in Atom and using the "Script"-plugin (like i am), you can set Environment Variables with Shift+cmd+I to bring up the Run-options :) Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are trying to process a non-ascii character. You need to encode it in unicode with `.encode('utf-8')`

Comment: Thanks for answering. _response_ is a list object, so when I try that, Im getting this back: **AttributeError**: 'list' object has no attribute 'encode'

Comment: try setting the encoding at the top of the file with `# -*- coding: utf8`

Comment: The `coding:` trick only works when the problem is in your Python source code. In this case it isn't, it's in the string coming from JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Since your response is a bytes object, you need to decode to get back the string

```
import http.client
import json

api_key = 'hidden'
connection = http.client.HTTPConnection('api.football-data.org')
headers = { 'X-Auth-Token': api_key, 'X-Response-Control': 'minified' }
connection.request('GET', '/v1/competitions', None, headers)
print (connection.getresponse().read().decode("utf-8"))
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. _response_ is a list object, so when I try that, Im getting this back: **AttributeError**: 'list' object has no attribute 'encode'

Comment: Updated my answer. Try that now

Comment: Thanks again! now im getting this: **AttributeError**: 'dict' object has no attribute 'encode'