# How to resolve UnicodeEncodeError storing data in json format

Tags: python, python-unicode

I have scraped data from a website but for some items it shows me below error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\2019' in position 4: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I have even put "# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-" at the top of the document but it is not worked. Please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UnicodeEncodeError on API-call (json)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45154063/unicodeencodeerror-on-api-call-json)

Comment: That's not what `# -- coding: utf-8 --` is for. Show your code.

Comment: @michael . you need to encode the data while printing it or writing it to file , what you did is a way specifying the encoding of a Python file

Comment: Are we supposed to guess what your code was doing at this point and what your data looks like ?

Answer (score 1):

Either always consider the `unicode` content or remove the `unicode` content entirely. The error is occurring because you (or some library methods you're using) are trying to convert `utf-8` content into ascii without ignoring the errors.

```
# Ignore unicode content
content_string = content_string.encode('ascii', 'ignore')

# Or make sure you handle unicode content as such. It would have been
# easier if you're using Python3x.
```

The purpose of `# -- coding: utf-8 --` is to allow explicitly adding Unicode content into a python code file, and not to set the default encoding.

```
# -- coding: utf-8 --
book_name = 'Les Misérables'
```